# Can Xamarin be use to create client sdks for native iOS and Android Apps?

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible to create a sdk for our SAAS product in Xamarin that can be consumed in native apps written for IOS (ObjectiveC and Swift) and Android (Java and Phonegap)?

If yes, then the integration in the app with Xamarin built sdk any different from sdks built using native laguages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. There are a few statements about this topic in the [Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/6730/#Comment_6730). However, they are far away from any practical solution.